# Push to array with key based on value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array and then another array where the structure is similar but not identical (it shares common keys).

It looks something like this:

```
[my_Array] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => o1
                [item_details] => original item 1 
                [booking_date] => 2015-02-14
                [booking_start] => 18:30:00
                [booking_end] => 18:35:00
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => o2
                [item_details] => original item 2
                [booking_date] => 2015-02-14
                [booking_start] => 19:30:00
                [booking_end] => 19:35:00
            )
    )


[new_array] => Array
    (
        [item_details] => new item 
        [booking_date] => 2015-02-14
        [booking_start] => 18:55:00
    )
```

The first array is already ordered on the booking_start key, but I want to push the new array item to the first array in order of booking_start.

I'm guessing that array splice is my friend here but how work out what position I need to push to?

So my result would look like this:

```
[my_Array] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => o1
                [item_details] => original item 1 
                [booking_date] => 2015-02-14
                [booking_start] => 18:30:00
                [booking_end] => 18:35:00
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [item_details] => new item 
                [booking_date] => 2015-02-14
                [booking_start] => 18:55:00
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [title] => o2
                [item_details] => original item 2 
                [booking_date] => 2015-02-14
                [booking_start] => 19:30:00
                [booking_end] => 19:35:00
            )
    )
```

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: @Tom Do you want to push the new item array in order of booking_start so that in your case thew new array comes on 1st index of existing array.

Comment: @dev_khan Please see my addition...

Comment: Why `array_splice`? Why not just push and reorder with `usort`?

Comment: Just an observation: var_export  far better than print_r for example data, because with the ouput of var_export: copy&paste, 3 lines of code _showing_ what you want to know, done. With print_r: hm, do I re-format the data for that little question ...nope, next question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First push new_array into my_array and use `usort`

```
 array_push($my_Array, $new_arr);
 usort($my_Array, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['booking_start'] - $b['booking_start'];
 });
```

Comment: had to convert the time to seconds but this got me there... thanks